# BPEL undeclared variable

Tags: bpel

i get an error when compiling a BPEL process( i use Apache ODE and Eclipse BPEL Designer):
error:

```
[UnrecognizedVariableDeclaration] The declaration of the variable "Iterator" was not recognized.
```

this is how the Iterator is being defined

```
          <bpel:variable name="Iterator" type="xsd:int"></bpel:variable>
```

and because the declaration was not recognized i get another error afterwards, when i reference the variable :

```
<bpel:assign name="copy_counter" validate="no">
                      <bpel:copy>
                        <bpel:from variable="Counter"></bpel:from>
                        <bpel:to variable="Iterator"></bpel:to>
                      </bpel:copy>
                    </bpel:assign>
```

What coulf be the problem here?. i have no idea, because i do not see a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. I looked at the imports and definitions of namespaces in my BPEL process(they are in the beginning of the whole document) and the namespace xsd was not declared. So i added the namespace declaration and it worked.